# Printing a Checkboard without using Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, multidimensional-array

I am trying to do print a checkerboard using arrays and without importing any packages like Numpy.  The code should print back

```
X 0 X 0 X 0 X 0
0 X 0 X 0 X 0 X
X 0 X 0 X 0 X 0
0 X 0 X 0 X 0 X
X 0 X 0 X 0 X 0
0 X 0 X 0 X 0 X
X 0 X 0 X 0 X 0
0 X 0 X 0 X 0 X
```

This is what I have written

```
Checkerboard = [[0]*8 for i in range(8)]
for i in Checkerboard:
  p = 0
  q = 0
  for j in i:
    if q % 2 == 0 and p % 2 == 0:
      Checkerboard[i][j] = "X"
    elif q % 2 == 1 and p % 2 == 1:
      Checkerboard[i][j] = "X"
    p += 1
for i in Checkerboard:
  for j in Checkerboard:
    print(j, end='')
  print('')
```

But it keeps getting the error:

```
Checkerboard[i][j] = "X"
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list
```

Can anyone help me solve the problem or give some tips?
(This is a hw assignment)

Comment: `for i in checkerboard...` `i` is a sublist, not an integer that you can use to index. You can iterate over the indices instead of the object, like `for i in range(len(checkerboard))...`

Comment: ```for i in Checkerboard``` iterates over the 2D array. You're iterating over a list of lists. So if ```i``` is a list, how can you do ```Checkerboard[i][j]```? ```i``` is not an integer. Maybe you could do something like ```for i, sublist in enumerate (Checkerboard)``` giving you access to both the sublist _and_ the index of it.

Comment: We expect you to perform basic diagnosis to include with your post.  At the very least, print the suspected values at the point of error and trace them back to their sources.
In many cases, doing this basic diagnosis will show you where the problem lies, and you won't need Stack Overflow at all.

Comment: Where have you printed the value of the indices that are causing the problem?  What don't you understand about the values, or how they're used?  As the posting guidelines tell you, "Make it easy for others to help you."  Using meaningless variable names and packing them into sub-standard spacing does *not* make others want to read your code.

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Your posted code doesn't run, due to syntax errors.

Comment: Sorry I did not realize there were syntax errors I have edited it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Checkerboard = [["0"] * 8 for i in range(8)]
for i in range(len(Checkerboard)):
    for j in range(len(Checkerboard[i])):
        if i % 2 == 0 and j % 2 == 0:
            Checkerboard[i][j] = "X"
        elif i % 2 == 1 and j % 2 == 1:
            Checkerboard[i][j] = "X"


for place in Checkerboard:
    print(place, end='')
    print('')
```

I updated your code and made a few changes.
The problem you have tried to change an a place in the board in this way:

```
Checkerboard[i][j] = "X"
```

But i and j are not declared as an index.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I just realized that I had gotten the printing the array and indexing the array mixed up.

Answer (score 2):

If you would use comprehension your solution would look like this:

```
Checkerboard = [[0 if (i % 2 == 0 and j % 2 == 1) or (i % 2 == 1 and j % 2 == 0) else 'X' for j in range(8)] for i in range(8)]

Checkerboard

[['X', 0, 'X', 0, 'X', 0, 'X', 0],
 [0, 'X', 0, 'X', 0, 'X', 0, 'X'],
 ['X', 0, 'X', 0, 'X', 0, 'X', 0],
 [0, 'X', 0, 'X', 0, 'X', 0, 'X'],
 ['X', 0, 'X', 0, 'X', 0, 'X', 0],
 [0, 'X', 0, 'X', 0, 'X', 0, 'X'],
 ['X', 0, 'X', 0, 'X', 0, 'X', 0],
 [0, 'X', 0, 'X', 0, 'X', 0, 'X']]
```

Or using finer print:

```
for i in Checkerboard:
    for j in i:
        print(j, end=' ')
    print()

X 0 X 0 X 0 X 0 
0 X 0 X 0 X 0 X 
X 0 X 0 X 0 X 0 
0 X 0 X 0 X 0 X 
X 0 X 0 X 0 X 0 
0 X 0 X 0 X 0 X 
X 0 X 0 X 0 X 0 
0 X 0 X 0 X 0 X
```